# Installing sbteclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt, sbteclipse

i have problems top use [sbteclipse](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse)

What I have done:

- went to my global sbt folder.
- created a plugins folder
- created the file plugins.sbt with `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.1.0")`
- went to my eclipse project and created a build.sbt file
- it contains:

> name := "foo"
>
> ```
> version := "1.0"
>
> scalaVersion := "2.9.2"
>
> libraryDependencies += "net.java.dev.jna" % "jna" % "3.4.0"
> ```

- I am selecting the project folder in my cmd. and type `sbt eclipse`

But I always get the following error

```
[error] Not a valid command: eclipse (similar: help, alias)
[error] Not a valid project ID: eclipse
[error] Expected ':'
[error] Not a valid key: eclipse (similar: deliver, licenses, clean)
[error] eclipse
[error]        ^
```

ps: I am using Windows. I am also using sbt 0.12

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your global sbt folder is at `%USERPROFILE%\.sbt` (`C:\Users\<username>\.sbt` most likely). So your plugins should be defined at `%USERPROFILE%\.sbt\plugins\plugins.sbt`

Failing this you can add it to your project directly. Add the file path is `<project_root>\project\plugins.sbt`.  If the `project` directory doesn't exist you will need to create it.

Comment: Mine is in `%USERPROFILE%\.sbt\plugins\build.sbt` (not `plugins.sbt`) and it works OK

Comment: You can name it anything as long as its in the plugins directory and has the extension "sbt"

Comment: Mine is  "~\.sbt\0.13\plugins\build.sbt". When using Version => 0.13 I think the folder is extended by the version info

Answer (score 0):

I think that I might have found a solution. First, the default directory checked for plugins configuration is 'USER_HOME/.sbt/plugins' and NOT 'USER_HOME/.sbt/0.13/plugins'.

Secondly, the sbt version specified seems to matter. In 'PROJECT_HOME/project/build.properties', there's an 'sbt.version' property. If the version of sbt specified in this file is different from the actually installed version of sbt, there's likely to be an issue. I think I was affected more so by this because I'm using an Activator template and it already had 'sbt.version' specified in this 'build.properties' file.

While nosing around, I came across this

"Support for plugin configuration in project/plugins/ has been removed. It was deprecated since 0.11.2" from sbt website at http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/Community/ChangeSummary_0.13.0.html. I still see a lot of guys pointing that it should be configured in 'PROJECT_HOME/projects/plugins.sbt'. I think this is very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar a issue and [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37708453/441652) to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24687698/441652).

I tried "everything" and, eventually, I just had to update my `sbt` from `0.13.1` to `0.13.9`.