# Create a new play scala project shows error in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, playframework, sbt, typesafe-activator

I am new to `play framework(Scala)`,I created a new project using 
`activator new sample play-scala` command, sample is my project name.Then I successfully ran a project using `activator run` command .When I ran a `activator eclipse` command it showed

```
[error] Not a valid command: eclipse (similar: help, alias)
[error] Not a valid project ID: eclipse
[error] Expected ':'
[error] Not a valid key: eclipse (similar: deliver, licenses, clean)
[error] eclipse
```

So from some internet suggestions I added
`addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.5.0")`

this line into my sample project's `plugins.sbt` file.This fixed the not a valid command error but When I imported a project into eclipse it showed a 
`object index is not a member of package views.html` error please help me to fix the error

**plugins.sbt**

```
// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.0")

// web plugins

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.6")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.3")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.7")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.1.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.5.0")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

create a new file plugins.sbt inside the project folder.

Sample directory path

```
C:\Workspace\PlayFramework\activator-1.3.6-minimal\play-java-intro\project\
```

Add the below content to the file

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")
```

Then run the eclipse command

```
activator eclipse
```

This worked for me without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

under your project folder does \project\build.sbt or \project\plugins.sbt  existed?
if not exist, you need to manualy create one.

similar issue [Installing sbteclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12983900/installing-sbteclipse)

Comment: I have `\project\plugins.sbt` in my project. I edited this question with `plugins.sbt` file please have a check on.

Comment: If you have plugin.sbt then you needn't add anything for that. If you run "activator eclipse" has some error, then clean the folders(.ivy2) and rerun the command. first you need to make sure the "activator eclipse" has no error.

Comment: how to clean a project folder? what is meant by .ivy2?

Comment: .ivy2 is the hidden folder in your home folder, if you using linux like system, you need to use "ls -a" to display it. The folder is used to cache java and scala packages. If you run "activator eclipse"  has error message for package download error, you remove the folder and redo the action may resolve the issue. First of all, make sure "activator eclipse" has no error. Then import the project using eclipse.

Comment: I am using Windows machine, If I use `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")` It shows  
`[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbt
eclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;4.0.0: not found` exception

Comment: When I used `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "3.0.0") ` It ran activator eclipse command successfully but showed a `object index is not a member of package views.html` error

Comment: That's a known issue for sbt . You should add "EclipseKeys.createSrc := EclipseCreateSrc.All" to your plugin.sbt, and rerun "activator eclipse" after that reopen the eclipse, may fix the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79335/discussion-between-jamal-and-wherby).

Comment: Your project I opened with latest Scala IDE 4.1 then the error occur, and I open with Scala IDE 3.0.4, every thing goes fine. Though there has error, you also could run the project using "activator run" to start your project. It's not a code level issue, it is only IDE bug. If you can't download old Scala version, I suggest you using Intellij as IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a long time ago. The solution was to create following two directories (at least one did not exist yet):

```
target/scala-2.11/src_managed/main
target/scala-2.11/twirl/main
```

I can't remember where I found the solution (or what the explanation of the error message was) but I hope this helps.

BTW, what's your ScalaIDE version? I currently use 4.1.0 <s>and I don't see this issue anymore</s>.

**Update:**

I created a new play project and suddenly encountered the same issue myself. There is an [older thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28458597/object-index-is-not-a-member-of-package-views-html-when-opening-scala-play-pro) dealing with this problem but unfortunately without any generally accepted solution.

The solution that worked or me was to update the project's Java Build Path and add these two source folders:

```
target/scala-2.11/routes/main
target/scala-2.11/twirl/main
```

Comment: I have both directories in my 
`target/scala-2.11/src_managed/main`
`target/scala-2.11/twirl/main`
project target folder. but target/scala-2.11/src_managed/main folder is empty it doesnt contains anything.target/scala-2.11/twirl/main folder conatins folder with the name `views`  `views/html/` conatins both files namely `index.template.scala` and `maintemplate.scala` 
Scala IDE version:4.3.0

Comment: Folders should be okay then. (I just realized that my initial play project does not have the src_managed folder).

Comment: Concerning the IDE version: 4.3.0 is your eclipse version and I was actually referring to the stand-alone ScalaIDE version (4.1.0 final is just a week old). You may want to give ScalaIDE a try. But if you want to stick with eclipse + Scala plugin I would suggest to update both eclipse and the scala plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$ activator clean compile` and then refresh project in Eclipse Package Explorer. After this action Eclipse will be in sync with project files.

Answer (score 0):

I found adding the plugin to the project directory didn't work for me.. dont know why.. (I'm using activator 0.13).

What I did...

create a directory called /.sbt/0.13/plugins
create a file called /.sbt/0.13/plugins/plugins.sbt

`addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.5.0")`

that worked.. the 2.5 version is super old.. so probably 4.0.0 or something would be better.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue upgrading from play 2.3 to play 2.5, just added `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")` to plugins.sbt but still having error Not a valid command: eclipse

So i realized that i had another sbt file under /project 'activator-sbt-eclipse-shim.sbt', i don't know why it was there but it was using and old version `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.3.0")`

i just changed that file to the right version and it worked